# XML To ListView Errors

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, listview, xml-parsing

I keep getting errors with this, and can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code

```
private void _FixSave_Offline_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument NewGame = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    NewGame.Load(Application.StartupPath + "//Files//Checks_Offline.xml");

    foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode nameNode in NewGame.SelectNodes("//Games//NewGame"))
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(nameNode.Attributes["Name"].InnerText);
    }
}
```

And here is the XML Layout

```
<Games>
 <NewGame>
   <Name></Name>
   <Check></Check>
   <Static></Static>
   <Location></Location>
   <Start></Start>
   <Length></Length>
   <FoundBy></FoundBy>
   <Verified></Verified>
</NewGame>
```

Here's is the error I keep getting

[image: Error Message]

and visual studio highlights the following code:

```
listView1.Items.Add(nameNode.Attributes["Name"].InnerText);
```

I've tried using not only "//" but also "/" so anything that will fix this will be more than welcome, b/c I can't for the life of me see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is the `nameNode` object null or is `nameNode.Attributes["Name"]` null?  If it is happening at the Attributes collection, then it can't find an attribute at the current node named "Name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, you're looking for an attribute with the name of "Name", but there are no attributes on any of the XML elements in your example.

I believe you want the content of the Name node:

```
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode nameNode in NewGame.SelectNodes("//Games//NewGame/Name"))
{
    listView1.Items.Add(nameNode.Value);
}
```

You might have to play with the XPath expression a bit, depending on the actual structure of your XML document.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see your XML example for some reason, but make sure you are distinguishing between [Elements and Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp)

Also, make sure that the attribute/element is spelled "Name" exactly. I believe it is case sensitive.

--

Edit: Now I am able to view your XML, it appears that "Name" is actually an element, rather than an attribute.

Try using the [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sss31aas.aspx) property, or the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx) property instead of `nameNode.Attributes`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.  Turns out that I the error was due to virtuallist = true.  Tim I modified your code above just a little to get the result I wanted.  Here's the code for anyone to use for future ref.

```
private void _FixSave_Offline_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Xml.XmlDocument NewGame = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
   NewGame.Load(Application.StartupPath + "//Files//Checks_Offline.xml"); 

   foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode nameNode in NewGame.SelectNodes("//Games//NewGame/Name"))
    {
       listView1.Items.Add(nameNode.InnerText);
    }

}
```

And here's a quick screenshot for the given result.

[image: Screen Shot Of Result]

Hope this helps others as well.  Thanks to the above people who commented me on this, and big thanks to Tim.